# Remove button does not work as intended (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const myLibrary = [];

function Book(title,author,pages,read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
    this.info = function(){
        return title + " by " + author + ", " + pages + " pages, "+ read ? "read":"not read yet";
    }
}
function loopThroughLibrary(){
    const myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.innerText = myLibrary[0].title;
}

function addBookToLibrary(Book) {
    myLibrary.forEach((book,index) => addBookToGrid(book,index));
}

function openPopup(){
    const window = document.getElementById("popup-window");
    window.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

const popupBtn = document.getElementById("open-popup");
popupBtn.addEventListener("click",openPopup);

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");


const bookContainer = document.getElementById("book-container");


function addBookToGrid(book,index){
        const newBook = document.createElement("div");
        newBook.classList.add("book-template");
        newBook.innerHTML = `<div class="bookProperties">
            <h3>Title: ${book.title}</h3>
            <p>Author: ${book.author}</p>
            <p>Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
            <p>Read?: ${book.read}</p>
            <button type="button" class="remove-button" data-index="${index}"> REMOVE </button>
        </div>`;
        
        // Add an event listener to the remove button
        bookContainer.appendChild(newBook);

        const removeButton = newBook.querySelector(".remove-button");
        removeButton.addEventListener("click", deleteBook);
            
    }
    
function render(startIndex=0){
    console.log("render called")

        for (let i = startIndex; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
            addBookToGrid(myLibrary[i], i);
        }
    }
    
 function deleteBook(e) {
    const index = e.target.dataset.index;
    console.log(myLibrary)

    myLibrary.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(myLibrary)

    render();
    }
    

function addBookToList(){
    const book = {
        title: document.getElementById("name").value,
        author: document.getElementById("author").value,
        pages: document.getElementById("pages").value,
        read: document.querySelector('input[name="read"]:checked').value
    };
    myLibrary.push(book);
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("author").value = "";
    document.getElementById("pages").value = "";
    document.querySelector('input[name="read"]:checked').checked = false;
    addBookToGrid(book);
}


submitBtn.addEventListener("click",addBookToList);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click",openPopup);
```

```css
html,body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin:0;
}

#open-popup {
    width: 8em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 15%;
    height:6vh;
    font-size: 2vh;;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header{
    background-color: #00796b; /* Teal */
    color: white;
}

.popup-window-inner{
   
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Light gray */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}



.radio-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.radio-container div {
    display:flex;
    width:100px;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
fieldset{
    border:0;
}
.labelinput{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap:20px;
    
}
input{
    background-color: rgba(12, 74, 74, 0.081);
    accent-color: rgba(12, 74, 74);
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 25px;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    border:0px;
}
.form{
    margin:auto auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:15px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Light gray */
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="number"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.submit-btn{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    font-size: 25px;
}
legend{
    margin:25px auto;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size:30px;
    color:rgb(0,0,0)
}
.book-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width:100vh;

}
.book-list{
    
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.book-template{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height:25vh;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.book-properties{
    display:flex;
    gap:5px;
    padding:15px;
}
button{
    background-color: #00796b;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #005a4e; /* Slightly darker shade */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Book library</h1>
      </div>
        <button id = "open-popup">Add new book</button>

        <div class="popup-window" id = "popup-window">
            <div class="popup-window-inner">
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                      <legend>Add New Book</legend>
                      <div class = "form">
                        <div class = labelinput>
                          <label for="name">Name</label>
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class = labelinput>
                          <label for="author">Author</label>
                          <input type="text" name="author" id = "author"/>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class = labelinput>
                          <label for="pages">Pages</label>
                          <input type="number" name="pages" min="1" id = "pages"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "radio-container">
                          <p>Read?</p>
                          <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="read" id = "readYes" value = "Yes"/>
                            <label for="readYes">Yes</label>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="read" id = "readNo" value = "No"/>
                          <label for="readNo">No</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button class = submit-btn id = "submit-btn" type="button" >Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="book-list">
        <h1>Book list</h1>
        <div class="book-container" id = "book-container">
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i have here is a basic vanilla js library app. I am adding new books with submit button to both my grid and to myLibrary array, each having an index in its remove button as data-index property value. However, there is a problem with the remove button, it is not responding.  I am adding all js html css so you can reproduce the problem.Any ideas on the css part is also appreciated.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a bare minimal example. And please use the snippet-functionality on this site.

Comment: `e.target["data-index"]` is wrong. You want `e.target.dataset.index`.

Comment: @Pointy thank you, it is still not working though.

Comment: Inside addBookToList(), you are calling addBookToGrid() with one argument when it expects 2. Which leads to data-index being undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deleteBook` function does not manipulate the DOM only the `myLibrary` list. The render function only adds content to the DOM but does not remove any.

A quick & dirty fix is to clear the `bookContainer` before rendering all elements. This is not very efficient in terms of performance but for such a small application is doesn't hurt.

If you want to do it right you should delete the target element with `element.remove()` or even better use a modern UI framework.

On top of that, the call to `addBookToGrid` is now called with the second required argument (`index`) to avoid removing the wrong book from the list.

```js
const myLibrary = [];

function Book(title,author,pages,read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
    this.info = function(){
        return title + " by " + author + ", " + pages + " pages, "+ read ? "read":"not read yet";
    }
}
function loopThroughLibrary(){
    const myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.innerText = myLibrary[0].title;
}

function addBookToLibrary(Book) {
    myLibrary.forEach((book,index) => addBookToGrid(book,index));
}

function openPopup(){
    const window = document.getElementById("popup-window");
    window.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

const popupBtn = document.getElementById("open-popup");
popupBtn.addEventListener("click",openPopup);

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");


const bookContainer = document.getElementById("book-container");


function addBookToGrid(book,index){
        const newBook = document.createElement("div");
        newBook.classList.add("book-template");
        newBook.innerHTML = `<div class="bookProperties">
            <h3>Title: ${book.title}</h3>
            <p>Author: ${book.author}</p>
            <p>Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
            <p>Read?: ${book.read}</p>
            <button type="button" class="remove-button" data-index="${index}"> REMOVE </button>
        </div>`;
        
        // Add an event listener to the remove button
        bookContainer.appendChild(newBook);

        const removeButton = newBook.querySelector(".remove-button");
        removeButton.addEventListener("click", deleteBook);
            
    }
    
function render(startIndex=0){
    console.log("render called")
        bookContainer.innerHTML = '';
        for (let i = startIndex; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
            addBookToGrid(myLibrary[i], i);
        }
    }
    
 function deleteBook(e) {
    const index = e.target.dataset.index;
    console.log(myLibrary)

    myLibrary.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(myLibrary)

    render();
    }
    

function addBookToList(){
    const book = {
        title: document.getElementById("name").value,
        author: document.getElementById("author").value,
        pages: document.getElementById("pages").value,
        read: document.querySelector('input[name="read"]:checked').value
    };
    myLibrary.push(book);
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("author").value = "";
    document.getElementById("pages").value = "";
    document.querySelector('input[name="read"]:checked').checked = false;
    addBookToGrid(book, myLibrary.length-1);
}


submitBtn.addEventListener("click",addBookToList);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click",openPopup);
```

```css
html,body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin:0;
}

#open-popup {
    width: 8em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 15%;
    height:6vh;
    font-size: 2vh;;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header{
    background-color: #00796b; /* Teal */
    color: white;
}

.popup-window-inner{
   
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Light gray */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}



.radio-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.radio-container div {
    display:flex;
    width:100px;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
fieldset{
    border:0;
}
.labelinput{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap:20px;
    
}
input{
    background-color: rgba(12, 74, 74, 0.081);
    accent-color: rgba(12, 74, 74);
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 25px;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    border:0px;
}
.form{
    margin:auto auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:15px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Light gray */
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="number"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.submit-btn{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    font-size: 25px;
}
legend{
    margin:25px auto;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size:30px;
    color:rgb(0,0,0)
}
.book-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width:100vh;

}
.book-list{
    
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.book-template{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height:25vh;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.book-properties{
    display:flex;
    gap:5px;
    padding:15px;
}
button{
    background-color: #00796b;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #005a4e; /* Slightly darker shade */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Book library</h1>
      </div>
        <button id = "open-popup">Add new book</button>

        <div class="popup-window" id = "popup-window">
            <div class="popup-window-inner">
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                      <legend>Add New Book</legend>
                      <div class = "form">
                        <div class = labelinput>
                          <label for="name">Name</label>
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class = labelinput>
                          <label for="author">Author</label>
                          <input type="text" name="author" id = "author"/>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class = labelinput>
                          <label for="pages">Pages</label>
                          <input type="number" name="pages" min="1" id = "pages"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "radio-container">
                          <p>Read?</p>
                          <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="read" id = "readYes" value = "Yes"/>
                            <label for="readYes">Yes</label>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="read" id = "readNo" value = "No"/>
                          <label for="readNo">No</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button class = submit-btn id = "submit-btn" type="button" >Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="book-list">
        <h1>Book list</h1>
        <div class="book-container" id = "book-container">
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated the code and the addBookToGrid() is now called with the required 2nd arguments. Otherwise, the code is still buggy and the wrong book is removed.